# Examples of expansive homeomorphisms with the specification property that are neither symbolic nor factors of mixing SFT nor product of thereof

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics, hyperbolic-dynamics, topological-dynamics

I am looking for nontrivial examples of expansive homeomorphisms with the specification property on compact metric spaces. Here, by a ``trivial'' example I understand a subshift with the specification property or an expansive factor of a mixing shift of finite type (the latter class includes mixing (pseudo-) Anosov diffeomorphisms or a Cartesian product of systems within the former two classes.

Let me recall definitions. Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $T\colon X\to X$ be a homeomorphism. We endow $X$ with a compatible metric $d$. We say that $T$ is *expansive* if there exists a constant $\alpha>0$ such that if $x,y\in X$ and $d(T^n(x),T^n(y))\le \alpha$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $x=y$. Actually this property does not depend on the choice of $d$. We say that $T$ has the *specification property* if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is an integer $k\ge 1$ such that for every $x,y\in X$ and $n,m\ge 1$ there is $z\in X$ such that
$$d(T^i(x),T^i(z))\le\varepsilon\quad\text{for } 0\le i<n\qquad\text{and}\qquad d(T^{n+k+j}(z),T^j(y))\le\varepsilon\quad\text{for } 0\le j<m.$$
There are many symbolic systems (subshifts) with the specification property (recall that all subshifts are expansive), and Anosov topologically mixing diffeomorphisms also have the specification property and are expansive. But it seems that all examples except some subshifts are factors of mixing shifts of finite type. I wonder if examples of expansive homeomorphisms with the specification property that are neither symbolic nor factors of mixing SFT nor product of thereof are known.

Comment: Here is a cheap example that doesn’t seem to be in your list: take any subshift $Y$ of the full 2-shift with the  specification property (e.g the 2-sided beta shift for nice values of beta). Now there is a factor map from the full 2-shift to the solenoid. I think the image of $Y$ satisfies your criteria, right? Of course this sounds like cheating, but aren’t all examples of this form?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: But if $Y$ is a proper subshift, don't you get a zero-dimensional (= subshift) image?

Comment: @VilleSalo: hmm. I suppose so. I will have to look for other cheap examples

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: He specifically wanted an expensive homeo.

Comment: Re-reading the question, I think Dominik means “symbolic” by subshift, rather than “isomorphic to a subshift”.